# Nginx reverse proxy only xhr/ajax requests

Tags: node.js, nginx

i have a laravel app and i want all requests to domain.test/api to be proxied to nodeJs but only if it is an xhr request. meaning that if a user types in a browser domain.test/api i want to give him a 404 but if the request is made with ajax i want to give him the response.

the following configuration proxies all:

```
location ~* ^\/api(.*)$ {
    proxy_set_header        Host $host;
    proxy_set_header        Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header        Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    proxy_read_timeout      300;
    proxy_pass              http://localhost:8081;
}
```

Is what i want to do possible using nginx? if so, please do suggest your solutions?

Comment: Unless you add some data (e.g. a special header) to the XHR request in your client code, the server (e.g. NGINX) cannot distinguish between a request made by browser navigation, client code, or other utilities (e.g. cURL). This isn't bulletproof though, utilities like cURL can be configured to use special headers, unless you're really clever it's not really possible to distinguish between the various possible clients making a request to your server.

Comment: So for example if add header['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest' for example to the XHR request i can pick it up by the server?

Comment: Yes, that's the basic idea, NGINX should have the ability to inspect the headers and conditionally forward the request, or respond with a 404.

Comment: great, i'll look it up. thanks @JakeHolzinger

Comment: Are the XHR/AJAX requests using the POST method? You can arrange for the GET method to return a 404 response by adding `if ($request_method != POST) { return 404; }`

Comment: unfotunately @RichardSmith i have GET & POST requests